# Guardar correctamente las variables en un json en javascript

Tags: javascript, json, js-cookie

Tengo un formulario con un input de texto, un checkbox de dos opciones y un input number que paso en mi codigo a través de getElementById, al insertar en el formulario no funciona correctamente y no guarda en la cookie resultado ninguno. El resultado de la cookie (estoy usando esta [API](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) ) se muestra vacio y no funciona correctamente al pulsar el boton de guardar, sino que sale el resultado cuando pulso el boton guardar y no tengo dato alguno escrito, creo que no esta pasando la variable correctamente a mi archivo Json y por algún motivo creo que no hago adecuadamente la funcion del boton guardar.

```js
document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener("click", function () {
  const res = document.getElementById("respuestas");
  const pregunta = document.getElementById("preg");
  const verdadero = document.getElementById("v");
  const falso = document.getElementById("f");
  const puntaje = document.getElementById("punt");

  let preguntas = {
    respuestas: [
      {
        nombre: "pregunta",
        respuesta: "true",
        puntuacion: "puntuacion",
      },
    ],
  };

  preguntas.respuestas[0].nombre = preguntas;
  if (verdadero == "verdadero") {
    preguntas.respuestas[0].respuesta = "true";
  } else if (falso == "falso") {
    preguntas.respuestas[0].respuesta = "true";
  }
  preguntas.respuestas[0].puntuacion = puntaje;

  let str = JSON.stringify(preguntas);

  res.innerHTML = "Respuestas:" + str;
  Cookies.set("preguntas", str);
  Cookies.get("preguntas");
});
```

Comment: Para empezar, esto: `document.getElementById("<algun id>");` devuelve un elemento HTML y no su valor. Por lo tanto, las asignaciones que pretendes hacer no serían correctas, a menos que estés intentado guardar *todo* el elemento, cosa que dudo. ¿Es eso lo que pretendes?

Comment: pretendo guardar lo que se escribe en el formulario, por ejemplo si el usuario escribe su nombre en el texto, marca verdadero y luego escribe 4 me gustaria que saliera Juan , verdadero y 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin entrar en detalles sobre el buen funcionamiento de la librería que mencionas, y debido a que en el Snippet de [StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) no podemos hacer uso de dicha librería para establecer o leer *Cookies*, entiendo que pretendes almacenar el valor de los elementos de un formulario en una *Cookie*.

El error lo tienes en la forma en la que capturas los valores, tal como te lo digo en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/416537/guardar-correctamente-las-variables-en-un-json-en-javascript?noredirect=1#comment743670_416537).

El valor de un campo `input` de tipo texto o numérico se captura o establece usando el atributo `value`:

```
let valor = document.getElementById(id).value;
```

Para el caso de elementos de tipo `checkbox` debes capturar su estado: `checked`, que será `true` si el mismo está marcado o `false` en caso contrario.

```
let chequeado = document.getElementById(id).checked;
```

Por ejemplo, lo siguiente muestra en pantalla el resultado de hacer esta captura de datos:

```js
function enviar(event) {
  let nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
  let respuesta = document.getElementById('respuesta').checked;
  let resultado = parseInt(document.getElementById('resultado').value);
  let pregunta = JSON.stringify({ nombre, respuesta, resultado });
  //Cookies.set("pregunta", pregunta);
  //Cookies.get("pregunta");
  console.log(pregunta);
  document.getElementById('res').innerText = pregunta;
}

document.getElementById('enviar').addEventListener('click', enviar);
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
  <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
  <input id="nombre" type="text">
  <br>
  <label for="respuesta">Respuesta: </label>
  <input id="respuesta" type="checkbox">
  <br>
  <label for="resultado">Resultado: </label>
  <input id="resultado" type="number">
  <br>
  <button id="enviar" type="button">Enviar</button>
</form>
<br>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Si bien esto podría ayudarte en tu problema, hay un detalle práctico en tu solución y es que un cliente pude tener deshabilitado el uso de *cookies* en el navegador o incluso puede tener algún *plugin* que evite la creación de las mismas.

Te sugiero que utilices la API [`localstorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) que te permitrá hacer lo que pretendes sin necesidad de establecer *cookies*.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// debido a la restricción del Snippet no podemos usarlo en un Snippet
localStorage.setItem('pregunta', pregunta);
let str = localStorage.getItem('pregunta');
console.log(str);
document.getElementById('res').innerText = str;
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! me has ayudado enormemente, debo hacerlo con cookies ya que estoy aprendiendo a usarlas, sabes porque podría ser que el boton guardar no me funcionara correctamente? he logrado solucionar lo de guardar los valores pero el boton guardar sigue sin funcionar bien

Comment: @Twins, podrías hacer otra pregunta con el nuevo error o problema, agrega el código `html` a la misma. Puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Vale gracias! :)